# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in chunk.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, .htaccess

I need your help please!

I have made deploy and build of aplication. but when i redirect for any page i have this error:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

I think it was because the browser await .html archive and chunk.js is open like this img

[print from error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCgqw.png)

the route is fine, he finds the route, but don't open file.

before some search i found things like a .htaccess and i have tryied but doesn't works.

i have tryied these two models of .htacess on public/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]

</IfModule>
```

```
Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

but it doesn't works too.

Server

```
const root = require('path').join(__dirname, 'client', 'build')
app.use(express.static(root));
app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile('index.html', { root });
})
```

i don't have any webserver, sorry, but im a student, and im still learning...

please help guys!

Comment: Please share your Javascript code...

Comment: You have a config for an Apache web server and code for an Express web server. Which web server are you actually running? If both, what is the connection between them? Do you have some code for a reverse proxy you haven't shared with us?

Comment: You have a URL that is being treated as JS and throwing an error because it has a `<` somewhere it shouldn't. Have you looked at that file? Why does it have a a`<` somewhere it shouldn't? Is that some JSX that hasn't been compiled? Or is your "Throw the HTML document for any URL that would normally 404 error" code throwing the HTML document at a browser expecting JS?

Answer (score 0):

If you using **Create React App** check your `build/asset-manifest.json` if have correct paths to the files. If not, change them manually or - what is better - change or set "homepage" value in `package.json` to proper one. And last tip - read carefully whole output of `npm run build` - it helped me. Whole bugfinding spends me 3 hours :(

Answer (score -1):

you add the line of code below to index.html in the public folder

> `<base href="your root path">`

Or you can refer to the link below:
https://skryvets.com/blog/2018/09/20/an-elegant-solution-of-deploying-react-app-into-a-subdirectory/