# Getting blank screen in sometimes with below error, after enabled the service worker in react js

Tags: reactjs

I need to auto refresh the react application after new code is pushed.

For that I have enabled the service worker and its working fine.

But in some time I'm getting blank screen while navigating with below error.

Syntax error: unexpected token '<'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYVxJ.png)

Comment: I'm struggling to fix this from last 2 weeks. Pl any having any idea?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your code and errors as **text** rather than as a screenshot. On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/q/67622794/18667225 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/58763819/18667225 and others ...